# how to play local video files in thumbnail overlay (similar to skype video calls)?

Tags: macos, video, quicktime, skype

I am very new to OSX, so far loving it. I really like how when you use Skype video call on OSX, and you change the primary focus to an app other than Skype, your video call is persistently visible on the screen as a small thumbnail sized overlay window, drawn above all your active applications.

I'd like to be able to play local video files in a similar manner, where the file is played in a small overlay window on top of all other windows, so that it's not covered up by my active application. I'd like to be able to watch some shows/movies while coding :)

Please let me know if this is possible, and how it can be done! I mainly use quicktime and VLC but if I need a different player to do this, that's okay too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

VLC : Go to Settings ->  Video -> Always on top [check] 
QuickTime  : Not possible without Extra Applications [like this](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22237/afloat).

Comment: the problem with this solution is 1) the video can't be made as small as the preview in Skype, and 2) the controls are still present / easily hit. I'm really looking for something where I can be watching it full screen, command-tab to a different application, and still be able to watch the video up in the corner of the screen. If you've used Skype I basically want that but for videos.